# Java using the replaceAll method

Tags: java

I have this code and it reads the text file into an array list and it prints out the array list. How can I have it read the file and store it into the array list and make any uppercase to lowercase letters and remove all punctuations? I have been looking all over the internet but couldn't find any solutions.

For example the text file can be:

```
It's a SuNnY day Today!
```

and the result should be:

```
its a sunny day today
```

.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class junk
{
    private static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));

            while (s.hasNext()) {
                list.add(s.next());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }

        int n = list.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

This line of code here works and does remove punctuation and makes letters lowercase but it only works if say String s = "Blah Blah Blah;;;"

```
String s1 = s.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}|\\d","").toLowerCase();
```

How can i make it work for my array list?

Comment: You can do those mutations while you're reading the files in to the list.

Comment: Have you started by going through the methods of `String` and learning what they do?

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you but here's a hint: try `toLowerCase()` and `replace()`

Comment: I got the line of code to do what I needed it too but it doesn't work for my array list. Any input is appreciated

Comment: as @Makoto says you can perform mutations as you read the data, alternatively you can iterate over the items in the list and modify them as you go. If this doesn't make sense I suggest you do some basic tutorials on ArrayLists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, looks the question updated during I writing the example code.
for the rephrased question, I guess you means the replaceAll take effect but not put back into ArrayList. repalceAll will generate a new String object and not affect the one in the array. so you needs to repaceAll just after read from the file and before "add" it into the ArrayList object.

========================

Try this code snippet, you may needs to tuning the judge of punctuation.

```
public void convert(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String s = reader.readLine();
        while (s != null) {
            // should work in this loop
            String s1 = s.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}|\\d","").toLowerCase();
            list.add(s1.toString());

        }
    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }

    for (String s : list) {
        // will not work in this loop
        //String s1 = s.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}|\\d","").toLowerCase();
    //  list.add(s1.toString());

        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```